# How do I download code from a Motor Control Board?

Tags: c, embedded, arm, microcontroller, texas-instruments

I have a stepper motor control board and I was wondering if it was possible to download the code from the board back to the PC. The board is a Luminary Micro Stepper Motor Control RDK with an ARM microcontroller.

Comment: Typically, this depends on whether your in-circuit debugger or programming device supports it, but also whether the MCU has a security option. All modern MCUs have such an option to prevent copy cats from stealing the code, but it isn't always enabled by default. I don't know how your particular MCU works in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Sure as long as the manufacturer of the board didn't enable the chip features that are built in specifically to not allow this type of behavior :-) (ya know, stealing or modifying their product).  Start with the data sheet and user's guide for the MCU, it should tell you everything you want to know.  Most likely they blew the JTAG fuse, enabled Code Read Protect, or used some other mechanism to prevent this.  You might check for bootstrap loader (BSL) functionality as well.